# How I can do stemming on a text file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, nlp, stemming, porter-stemmer

I want to use NLP stemming on a text file using node.js and then store it in some output file. Please let me know if you need more information.

I am using npm natural and PorterStemmer to do the same, but no success.

```
function doStem(data){
    var natural = require('natural');
    //do procesing using WordTokenizer & PorterStemmer.
    return nData;
}
```

Please let me know if I am using the correct approach or let me know if there is anything to be corrected.

UPDATE:

```
function doStemming(data){ 
  var natural = require('natural'); 
  var tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer(); 
  var tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(data); 
  stemmer = natural.PorterStemmer(data);
  var nData = stemmer.stem(tokens); 
  //console.log(nData); 
  return nData; 
}
```

This is what looks like I am doing. Please give some idea about how to do this using tokenization and PorterStemmer onto a text file but not on any specific word

Comment: Q: [How do I do] NLP stemming on a text file using node.js?  A: find a good library.  Q: I am using npm natural and PorterStemmer to do the same, but no success.  A: So... Q: what specific problems?  Q: Can you show us how to reproduce in an [MCVE]?

Comment: function doStemming(data){
    var natural = require('natural');
    var tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();
    var tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(data);
    stemmer = natural.PorterStemmer(data);
    var nData = stemmer.stem(tokens);
   
    //console.log(nData);
    return nData;
}
This is what looks like I am doing. Please give some idea about how to do this using tokenization and PorterStemmer onto a text file but not on any specific word.

Comment: The additional information helps.  I took the liberty of updating your original post, and adding some tags.  I'm still not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, or where you're blocked.

Comment: When I ran the updated code I got the below error



    ```stemmer = natural.PorterStemmer(data);
                    ^

TypeError: natural.PorterStemmer is not a function
    at doStemming (/home/vishabh/purify/stemer.js:39:21)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/vishabh/purify/stemer.js:20:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at fs.read (fs.js:2051:12)```

Comment: You've *got* to get out of the habit of posting code/log snippets in comments :(  Please update the main post with anything that should be "formatted".  ALSO: the error message suggests this is simply a Javascript coding error (*not* a problem with your stemmer library, or anything having to do with NLP or stemming per se).  Consider trying to reproduce the error in an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code snippet, and your error (thank you for posting both):

Code:

```
function doStemming(data){ 
  var natural = require('natural'); 
  var tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer(); 
  var tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(data); 
  stemmer = natural.PorterStemmer(data);
  var nData = stemmer.stem(tokens); 
  //console.log(nData); 
  return nData; 
}
```

Error:

```
stemmer = natural.PorterStemmer(data); 
                  ^ TypeError: natural.PorterStemmer is not a function 
  at doStemming (/home/vishabh/purify/stemer.js:39:21) 
  at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/vishabh/purify/stemer.js:20:21) 
  at emitOne (events.js:116:13) 
  at ReadStream.emit (events.js:211:7) 
  at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12) 
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11) 
  at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10) 
  at fs.read (fs.js:2051:12)
```

Cause: Like the error message says: "natural.PorterStemmer()" isn't a method. Rather, "natural.PorterStemmer" is an *OBJECT*.

Look here:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural#stemmers
>
> ```
> natural.PorterStemmer.attach();
> console.log("i am waking up to the sounds of chainsaws".tokenizeAndStem());
> console.log("chainsaws".stem());
> ```

In other words, you might try something like this:

```
function doStemming(data){ 
  var natural = require('natural'); 
  var tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer(); 
  var tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(data); 
  var nData = natural.PorterStemmer.stem(tokens); 
  console.log(nData); 
  return nData; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction and explanation. I was having difficulty of posting the code in proper format so I made it like that only. Actually my concern is to how would I do this process of stemming onto a big .txt file, because when it comes to big text file that would require the data to be divided into chunks and then stemming process has to be applied and finally it should be able to create a different output stemmed file altogether. I have checked so many places but couldn't get through the process correctly. Please let me know how would I do that successfully.

Comment: Also please let me know if this can be done using a python file and then calling in node.js or this can be done using node.js itself only.